# How to convert a list of model to multidimensional array c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, entity-framework

this the problem; I have a list and I would like to covert to a multidimencion array, this is the class:

```
public class Student{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

the list is,  (I am using EF);

```
var listStudent = db.Students.ToList();
```

I would to converte this list to something like this

string[,] new Value= db.Students.ToList();

Comment: What values will be stored in `string[,] new Value` and how? You can create extension method for `List<Student>` and write logic to convert the list to two-dimensional array. You can learn about extension method at [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Comment: And the most interesting - why would need this?

Comment: I need it like this becouse I need fill up a excel document

Comment: You haven't indicated what you want in the 2 dimensional array. A list is 1 dimensional.

Comment: I believe you're approaching this the wrong way. Are you just trying to turn your `Students` into a comma delimited file (CSV)?

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you do something like:

```
Student student1 = new Student();
Student student2 = new Student();
string[,] temp = { 
    { student1.FirstName, student1.LastName },
    { student2.FirstName, student2.LastName }
};
```

By the way, you should provide more details.

Comment: It is not what I want!!

Comment: What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved,
My idea was, how to convert a list of any object  to a multidimensional array, something like this:

1.- First my class:

```
public class Myclass{
 public string propr1 { get; set;}
 public string propr2 { get; set;}
 public string propr3 { get; set;}
}
```

2.- Make query using EF:

```
var listMyclass = db.Myclass.ToList();
```

3.- Use this method to convert this list to DataTable:

```
 public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
        //Get all the properties by using reflection   
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            //Setting column names as Property names  
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
        }
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {

                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

4.- get DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = ToDataTable<T>(listMyclass);
```

5.- And finally, pass all values from DataTable to multidimensional Array:

```
string[,] multidimensionalArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                multidimensionalArray[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString(); 
            }
        }
```

Thank you all..!!